# How to push eclipse workspace projects to git using GIT CMD desktop application?

Tags: github

I would like to synchronize all my eclipse workspace to a github repository. Please tell me the list of commands to do it.

Comment: Did you initially _clone_ your current workspace _from_ a GitHub repository?

Comment: Do you really want to do it by command line or if you can do it easily by eclipse it's also fine ?

Comment: I want to learn to do it both ways. Please help me.

Comment: Tim- I haven't cloned it from GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access **Git commands** from **CMD**. You have to set the `PATH` Environment Variables to Git's `bin` directory, mine is `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`.

Then configure your information for all local repo

```
git config --global user.name "[name]"
git config --global user.email "[email address]"
```

Create your repository on **GitHub**. Then go to your project directory(eclipse workspace projects) `git init [project-name]` and add all files to staging area `git add --all` or `git add *` Then commit it with some message `git commit -m “Initial Commit”` and then `git remote add origin <url>` then push your files to GitHub `git push origin master`

See this [GIT CHEAT SHEET](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/git-cheat-sheet/) to know more...

**Updated :**
Here is the [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwju0cjNpc7QAhWBP48KHWwnBDAQFggkMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Feducation.github.com%2Fgit-cheat-sheet-education.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEwN47tZ02URpordjfgXRq3byIBVg&bvm=bv.139782543,d.c2I) to download **GIT Cheat Sheet PDF**.

Comment: Are you talking about using GIT Bash?

Comment: Set the PATH Environment Variable to Git's bin directory @HadrianBlackwater .
This is my location of Git's bin : C:\Program Files\Git\bin

.Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look  ! 
[GIT CHEAT SHEET](https://services.github.com/kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the cheat sheet, but it doesn't quite answer my question. I would like to know how to synchronize all projects from my eclipse workspace.

Comment: Pay attention to my answer @HadrianBlackwater Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

If you cloned your Eclipse workspace from a GitHub repository, all you need to do is

```
git push origin master
```

If you didn't, you first need to create an empty repository on GitHub. Then copy and paste the URL at the top of the page for your new repo. From the command line type

```
git remote add origin <paste URL here>
```

Now you can use the same `git push` command as above to push your git history to the new GitHub repo.